# Difference between Scripting and Programming Language

Tags: scripting

What is difference between Scripting and Programming Language .

which is scripting and programming language below :-

Perl 
Python 
Ruby 
Groovy

Comment: You should probably google `Compiled vs. Interpreted Languages`.

Comment: They are *all* programming languages…

Comment: As per to me , scripting languages used for support(either in language or in program  like vmscript for ex  Microsoft office etc ) . And languages mentioned have their own developing capability , their own VMs even they have their web Frameworks solely upon these . So i also think , these are PROGRAMMING LANGUAGES . Could anyone having other views , please comment o.

Comment: As per the TIOBE index , shows the popularity of languages , put them in PROGRAMMING Language category .. 
http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Answer (score 9):

There is a huge difference between programming and scripting that is seemingly so close some times, it can be hard to distinguish. The main thing between the two is that with a program you can do anything that is possible with the computer. Scripting however is writing code that a program accepts and then does what you tell it. Scripting is limited to whatever the programmer allowed or programmed into it, to let you script(control). Even with Windows 7 [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), which allows you to do many, many things deep into the system, is but a script engine. The PowerShell itself now, is a program!

One other factor that makes it rather confusing is with programming languages them selves. Some limit what you can do, while others allow for more control. It starts to sound like scripting when I say that, but I guess the main thing I could say about programming and scripting is with scripting you are talking to a program, while Programming you are talking to the Operating System!

So, you want to control a program, Script! You want to control the computer, program!
and maybe just allow scripting in your program as well!

With that said, you need to understand that you can have more or less power over the computer depending on the programming language you choose. Scripting is way less power, but Programming has it's more complex (more power) languages as well.

All the ones you listed, Perl, Python, Ruby, and groovy are Programming Languages!

Some examples of Scripting would be like VBScript (A subpart of VB(Visual Basic) the programming language), jscript (Java Script, another subpart) and the oldest of all time, Batch programming in DOS! These would be the .bat files...

Answer (score 4):

I would consider scripting languages to be a sub-sets of programming languages. Usually scripting languages are interpreted and dynamic.

Comment: so , which one is scripting in nature in provided list ?

Comment: I would consider them all scripting languages.